# Map Reduceの仕組み・注意すべきことを知りたい (python map)

Tags: python

### Map Reduce を基にしたpythonのmap関数に関して

pythonで、例えばこんなmapの使い方があります。

```
a = map(lambda x:pow(x,2), range(100))
```

mapを使えば勝手に中で並列に処理してくれて高速だ、ということを聞いたことがあります。
しかし、勝手に中で並列に処理してくれるというのはどういう仕組みなのでしょう。
並列処理にできそうにない場合想定外の動きをする可能性はないでしょうか。
例えば

```
count = 0
def hoge(x):
  global count
  count += x
  return count
a = map(hoge, range(100))
```

みたいな場合です。
これはglobal変数に同時にアクセスできずおかしくなってしまうのかなと思ったのですが、想定通り（先頭から順に処理）の挙動をしてくれます。
map関数では内部でどういう並列化が行われているのでしょうか？
map関数を使うべきでない場合などあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 組み込み関数の`map`（並列処理はしてくれない）ではなく[Pool.map](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)のことでしょうか？

Comment: Pythonのmapは逐次処理ですので、この例は動きます。Hadoopなどで言う所のmap-reduceでは呼び出される関数に副作用や状態がある場合は実行できません。仮に力技で実装したとしても速度が出ないでしょう。